# Performance of scrappping WEB table in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, performance, web-scraping

This code is too slow. I need to transfer data from HTML table to excel worksheet. I can't use query table because the table is generated by POST method after pressing a button.
The table is 16 columns x 200+ rows

What can I do to make it work faster?

```
'GET THE TABLE
Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLDiv As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim TableSection As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim TableRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim TableCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim RowText As String
Dim row As Integer
Dim column As Integer

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Workbooks("Zautomatyzowany raport produkcyjny.xlsm").Worksheets("PressQualityHold")

row = 1
column = 1
'WAIT for IE
Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy
Loop


Set HTMLTables = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")

Workbooks("Zautomatyzowany raport produkcyjny.xlsm").Worksheets("PressQualityHold").Cells.Clear

For Each HTMLTable In HTMLTables
    'Debug.Print HTMLTable.ID, HTMLTable.className
    
    If HTMLTable.ID = "table_details" Then
        For Each TableSection In HTMLTable.Children
            'Debug.Print , TableSection.tagName
            
                If TableSection.tagName = "TBODY" Then
                    For Each TableRow In TableSection.Children
                        'RowText = ""
                        For Each TableCell In TableRow.Children
                            ws.Cells(row, column).Value = TableCell.innerText
                            'RowText = RowText & vbTab & TableCell.innerText
                            column = column + 1
                        Next TableCell
                        'Debug.Print , , RowText
                        row = row + 1
                        column = 1
                    Next TableRow
                End If
                
        Next TableSection
    End If
    
Next HTMLTable

IE.Quit
```

Comment: So I've found that one way to make it faster is to copy entire row from the HTML Table, but then it copies to one cell and later I'd have to parse the excel sheet in different way. I am not sure what would be faster.

Comment: Same happens when I try to copy entire table. Copies into 1 cell. Should I try doing that and then parsing the data? Is excel even able to hold this much data in one cell? Or maybe someone already knows easier method?

Answer (score 0):

I am very sorry to spam the forum, but I have found a solution to this.
I am not sure how and why this works, but it does exactly what I wanted.

```
'GET THE TABLE
Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLDiv As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim TableSection As MSHTML.HTMLTable
Dim TableRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim TableCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim RowText As String
Dim row As Integer
Dim column As Integer

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Workbooks("Zautomatyzowany raport produkcyjny.xlsm").Worksheets("PressQualityHold")

row = 1
column = 1
'WAIT for IE
Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy
Loop


Set HTMLTables = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")

Workbooks("Zautomatyzowany raport produkcyjny.xlsm").Worksheets("PressQualityHold").Cells.Clear

For Each HTMLTable In HTMLTables
    'Debug.Print HTMLTable.ID, HTMLTable.className
    
    If HTMLTable.ID = "table_details" Then
        For Each TableSection In HTMLTable.Children
            'Debug.Print , TableSection.tagName
            
                If TableSection.tagName = "TBODY" Then
                    
                    Set TableSection = HTMLTables(2)
                    Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject
                    Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
                    clipboard.SetText TableSection.outerHTML
                    clipboard.PutInClipboard
                    ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
        
                End If
                
        Next TableSection
    End If
    
Next HTMLTable

IE.Quit
```